# MYSQL: check if one row of result has specific value

Tags: mysql

I am using a select statement like this

```
SELECT color, form FROM userTable WHERE type = 42
```

and get as a result

> ```
>  color |   form    |
> --------------------
>  red   | circle    |
>  blue  | rectangle |
>  blue  | circle    |
> ```

However I would like to get only a single row which is 1 in column *color* if there exits a row of my result with blue color, otherwise 0, and which is 1 in column *form* if there exists a row of my result with a line form. So from the  above example the result should look like

> ```
>  color  |   form   |
>  -------------------
>     1   |     0    |
> ```

Is it possible to achieve this with an MySQL command?

Here is what I tried:

```
SELECT IF(color='blue', 1, 0) as color, IF(form='line', 1, 0) as form
FROM userTable WHERE type = 27 GROUP BY type
```

but I don't think this works since some of the rows fulfill the IF-conditions and others do not. I would need some statement which is like `IF THERE EXITS A ROW WITH COLOR = 'blue'` or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do it like this:

```sql
SELECT IF(COUNT(CASE WHEN color = 'blue' THEN 1 END) > 0, 1, 0) AS color,
       IF(COUNT(CASE WHEN color = 'line' THEN 1 END) > 0, 1, 0) AS form
FROM mytable
WHERE type = 42
GROUP BY type
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/24ec0e/2)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you :)!

Answer (score 1):

You can check 'if there exists a row' situation with function [COUNT()](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp).

`SELECT COUNT(color) FROM userTable WHERE color="blue"`, for example, returns with a single column and row, that makes this count.

You can expand this with conditions and more columns to make it fitting your purpose.